# ¿Se puede cambiar una palabra de una columna en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenta tarde. Tengo una tabla llamada fotoscec, donde tengo una columna llamada fotomapaedo, donde tengo varios registros en esta tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar la palabra Fotos/ por Fotos/estado/.
Es posible realizar esto?, muchas gracias por su atención

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu consulta a base de datos, debes agregar la función `REPLACE` al campo que trae los resultados que necesitas y sustituir dicho valor por el que deseas, en ese caso tu consulta podría quedar así:

```
SELECT REPLACE(fotomapaedo, "Fotos/", "Fotos/estado/") as fotomapaedo FROM nombre_de_mi_tabla
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update fotoscec
set fotomapeado = replace(fotomapeado, 'Fotos/', 'Fotos/estado/');
```

Usas la sentencia **update** para actualizar todos los valores de la **columna fotoscec** y a través de la **función** **replace**, haces la sustitución de cada valor del campo por la cadena nueva. Usando el **update** ya garantizas que toda la información quede correctamente salvada en la **base de datos**.

Si lo deseas posteriormente puedes hacer una consulta para ver los cambios realizados:

```
select fotomapeado 
from fotoscec
```

De esta forma visualizarás en una consulta la columna con todos sus valores cambiados.

Comment: Gracias luis, es que entre el c# y el sql a veces confundo como se representan las cadenas de texto

Comment: Agregaría un `WHERE fotomapeado NOT LIKE 'Fotos/estado/%'` para evitar que se duplique la cadena por error.